# Sending mouse click to VB6 windowless controls when is in a background desktop

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, vb6

I have a form VB6 with some windowless controls (without hWnd) in it.

I need simulate the mouse click on than controls when the window is in a background desktop.
This form references a C# DLL with interop.

I tried to use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) but it not works in background desktops.

I tried to use `PostMessage/SendMessage` with `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_BUTTONUP` but with windowless controls the click not raise.

What can I use to do this?

Comment: I don't have VB6 here to check nowadays, but I would simulate your mouseclick on the form that your windowless control is on and then check if the click's X and Y position is within the rectangle of your windowless control.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?854687-Windowless-UserControl-Question

Comment: Are you trying to send the input from the same VB6 process or from a different process? What do you mean by "background desktop"? When you tried PostMessage, which hWnd did you use?

Comment: So you have a VB6 application that references C# DLL and you want to send events from the C# DLL to the VB6 application window?

Comment: Run [inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to verify that you can see the vb6 controls you want to tinker with.  Do so with System.Windows.Automation in a C# program.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible sample so we're sure what we're talking about? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier see repo link in my answer,  I provided sample app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your controls are windowless, doesn't prevent you from doing that. You just have to ensure that you are sending the messages to the container window (the one that has its `hWnd` handle).

I tested the following code on VB6 app with windowless button. For me it simulates the click even for minimized window. The trick is to first send `WM_ACTIVATE` message, then the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP` pair:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Win32 API definitions
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd,  uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);


const uint WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

const int MK_LBUTTON = 1;

const int WA_ACTIVE = 1;

int MAKELPARAM(int p, int p_2)
{
    return ((p_2 << 16) | (p & 0xFFFF));
}

// The code
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Form1");

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, 0);

int lParam = MAKELPARAM(62, 68); // Button coordinates relative to window "client area"
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam);
```

See [this repo](https://github.com/vvv444/stackoverflow/tree/main/q76181152) for working code example -

1. Run `WLTest.exe` (Set Win XP compatibility mode in the .exe "Properties") and minimize it's window.
2. Then run the C# code and ensure the counter indeed increments in the VB6 window.

Comment: No, that's not supported. See [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) for more information. If you need to automate a UI, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @IInspectable Not true. See the code I added, it's working example with complete VB6 app.

Comment: If you don't know why it works, then it doesn't. Make sure to read the documentation for [`WM_ACTIVATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-activate). It's a message that's sent by the system. It is not designed to be sent (or posted) by applications.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree that the way I use here is not the officially supported way. But it works. The UI automation on the other hand doesn't seem suitable here because of the special nature of VB6 "windowless" components. So I proposed the only solution that de-facto seems working, even if unofficial.

Answer (score -2):

[You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). The same underlying principles apply to mouse input and when using `SendMessage`. In short, the system generating messages is only part of input processing. Faking those messages isn't going to magically cause the system to synthesize mouse input out of thin air.

If you need to inject input, then there's [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) for that. This API injects input events into the same input buffers that are filled by genuine hardware devices. As such they follow the same rules. Specifically, mouse input goes to the window that's under the current mouse position, so this won't allow you to generate mouse input for windows that aren't visible.

If you need to automate a UI (irrespective of whether it is visible), then [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is the only available infrastructure (unless the application in question provides its own, custom automation interface).

Comment: Does UI Automation API support simulating mouse click event on a given non visible window?

Comment: @vvv444 UI Automation doesn't simulate mouse clicks. It operates at a higher level of abstraction, allowing you to initiate actions (such as the action a UI would perform in response to a mouse click). UI Automation doesn't require a window to be visible to interact with or, nor does it even require a window at all.

Comment: The OP question is about interacting with the VB6 "windowless" components that don't have any representation from the PoV of Win32 API. This can be just seen as internal application logic that processes mouse/keyboard input and produces image painted on top of window. Thus, it seems UI automation has no tools of any kind to interact with these.

Comment: @vvv444 UI Automation doesn't require a window (as I literally just spelled out). If you feel like voicing an opinion, at least postpone that until *after* you've read through the documentation I liked to.

Comment: I actually already did skim it *before* answering and didn't find which facility there can be used to solve this specific question. That would be nice if you pointed out a concrete API and gave working code example instead of abstract claim that it can somehow be solved with the UI Automation framework.

Comment: @vvv444 There are literally tens of thousands of computer users with impaired vision that rely on assistive technology. Which is built on top of MSAA/UIA. Calling that off as an abstract claim is ignorant and dismissive. The framework is based on the [accessible tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-treeoverview) which you can navigate. You can use the [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to get that visualized if you're curious enough.

Comment: Again, I think you misunderstood the situation. Because of how VB6 windowless controls are implemented, these aren't seen by "accessible tree" / Inspect. Here is what you see using this tool: https://i.imgur.com/6B90w9L.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253544/discussion-between-vvv444-and-iinspectable).

Comment: @vvv444 I did not misunderstand the situation. I listed the possible options, exhaustively. If none of them work for some undisclosed VB6 controls, then you are out of options. Sometimes, the answer is that you cannot do that.